Direct image of a vector bundle defined on an open subscheme
Let $X$ be a noetherian irreducible scheme, of dimension $\geq 2$, $P\in X$ a closed point and $U=X\setminus\{P\}$. Let $\iota:U\to X$ be the inclusion morphism.
Let $E$ be a vector bundle on $U$, and suppose that it cannot be extended to a vector bundle on $X$. What can be said anyway about $\iota_*(E)$ ? Are there any cases covered in the literature ? In particular if $X$ is non reduced ?

TeX note: X \backslash \{P\} $X \backslash {P}$  probably doesn't space as you want. For better semantics with proper spacing, X \setminus \{P\} $X \setminus {P}$ does the job.  I edited accordingly.

What precisely do you want to know about $\iota_*(E)$?

It would be some kind of description. In particular when $E$ is a line bundle. I think that this is interesting when $X$ is not quasi projective and there are only few vector bundles on $X$. One would hope to find some on $X$ minus some points, which would be quasi projective (maybe this works only for surfaces).

The structure of $\iota_*(E)$ around $P$ only depends on an affine neighborhood of $E$, so this will not depend on whether $X$ is quasiprojective or not.

You are right, this is completely a local question.

If $X$ is normal, then $\iota_*E$ is reflexive. (Also, I assume you mean that $E$ is a locally free sheaf...)
